# What is the meaning of 厚重感？

Tags: meaning

This is from an interview text:

我从小就喜欢文学，而且对北大非常向往。在我眼里，北大的精华都在文史哲，它们有一种厚重感。

我从小就喜欢文学，
As a child I always liked literature

而且对北大非常向往。
and I longed to go to Beijing University.

在我眼里，
In my eyes,

北大的精华都在文史哲，
Beijing University is quintessentially a place for literature, history and philosophy,

它们有一种厚重感。
they have a ????

They are very important there??
They are taken very seriously there??
These subjects have great weight there??
These subjects are profoundly important there??
I feel they are profoundly important there??

How should I translate '它们有一种厚重感。'??

Edit: found this in iciba.com

Scotland is a unique and austere place, laden with history.

参考译文苏格兰是一个独特的地方,自然条件虽不得天独厚, 历史的厚重感却随处可见.

历史的厚重感却随处可见 laden with history

So maybe I can translate:
I feel it, the university, is laden with literature, history and philosophy
I feel it is laden with them.
I feel they ooze from the walls.

春节快乐，万事如意！

Comment: 北大 ie 北京大学 was founded before the PRC and pinyin. It kept its old English name Peking University (not Beijing University)

Answer (score 3):

厚重= thick and heavy

厚重感 = a thick and heavy feel

The most direct translation would be "a **thick and heavy feel**". It implies the air is filled with some sense that you can almost feel it's thickness and weight.

In the context of the quotes, **厚重感** can also be translated as "**a substantial feel**" or "**a feel of immensity**"

> [substantial](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/substantial) (adjective):
>
> 1. of **ample or considerable amount**, quantity, size
> 2. of **solid character or quality**; **firm**, **stout**, or strong

~

> [immensity](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/immensity)(noun):
>
> 1. **vastness**; **enormous extent**:
>    *the immensity of the Roman empire*.

Comment: Thanks Tang Ho. I'm sure in the right context your answer would be great, but I feel here that it is not quite the right answer. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Then I suggest "a feel of immensity "